# Postgres /Pgadmin Convert Characters t/f to Boolean values (TRUE/FALSE) in target database

Tags: boolean, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5

I have a CSV file that contains a number of columns with `t` / `f` values. I'm trying to write this data to Postgres using pgadmin.

The columns in the target table in postgres are set to type boolean which only accepts 'TRUE' 'FALSE'.

How might I convert these `t` / `f` values to `TRUE`/`FALSE` in order that my table import doesn't fail. Any hints or other approaches to this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: `t` and `f` [are acceptable strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-boolean.html) for a boolean column, so your data should import fine. If it's not, please show a sample of your data, the table schema, and the import error.

Comment: what cdhowie said plus: show us the command you use to import the file.

Comment: Are you **really** still using Postgres 9.1? If yes, you should plan the upgrade to a supported and maintained version now.

Comment: Problem solved. Forgot to add header when importing Many thanks for your assistance.